# Python Selenium - submitting form closes window which causes a connection reset error [WinError 10054]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to fill in a form. I click on a webelement which opens a new window which contains this form. I manage to fill in the form and click on 'OK'. This causes the pop-up window to close, which gives an error in python.

Below is the approach I took:

```py
default_window = driver.window_handles[0]
try:
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #This switches to the pop-up window
    #Code to fill in the form
    action.send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform() #This action submits the form and closes the window
except:
    driver.switch_to.window(default_window) #Switch back to the main form when the pop-up window is closed
```

I tried the try/except functions to work around the error. However, the connection with the default window cannot be restored.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I did find a workaround. I tested this form by clicking on 'Cancel' which shuts down the pop-up down immediately. Pressing 'Ok' takes some time to process the form which is sufficient to switch to the default window.